# Yii2 Basic: Automatic Login on two different project on the same server

Tags: mysql, yii2-basic-app

I've been googling a problem that is affecting most noob developers to yii2. Firstly i have created two project using yii2 basic. Now if i login in the one of the project, the other project automatically login as well. why is that? on both of them i have the same username but different passwords and it still login.I've read it has to do on some session on yii2. Can anybody shed light on the matter.

Comment: chane your `identityCookie` for `User` component

Comment: Thanks mien that did the trick.